# Why do my app crashes when trying to use DataOutputStream

Tags: java

Im trying create a app that post information to a web page using  DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
But it crashes if i try to do just that.

My app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml look something like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_MESSAGING_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk"/>

class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    public String info="";
    public String info2="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://mypage.nu/info.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            try {
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());//Something goes wrong  
            }catch(IOException e){     
                 e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
            String json="{'name':'test'}";
            out.writeBytes("x="+json);
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }...
```

I expect That i can retrieve `$obj = json_decode($_POST["x"], false);`

But it dies when trying to create `DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream`

Comment: what error do you get? just saying "it crashes" means very little

Comment: This is not about PHP or your IDE. Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I have some problem with running the application on my computer so must use my android device. The problem seems to have been something other than what I asked. Below I had a catch that was a bit wrong in itself .. sorry! Didn't see this before now. However, has not received information to the page than but now it does not crash :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the connection that you want an output stream.

```
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
```

See UrlConnection chapter:
[Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)